# Can I manually create system fields on a custom table?

Tags: c#, kentico

I'm currently developing a new Kentico 9 site that uses several custom tables. These tables already have data in them and are being leveraged within the code via the API. Whoever created the Custom Tables within Kentico unchecked several of the system fields during creation so that only the ItemGUID field would be created:

[image: System Fields on Custom Table]

Now that the Custom Table has already been created and is in use, is there anyway for me to create or re-add the other columns (ItemCreatedBy, ItemCreatedWhen, etc.) to this table? If so, how can this be accomplished?

---

Note: My current approach here is to create a new custom table with the fields I want and migrate the data into the new table (we do have upwards of 30 tables though so I'd rather not have to do this by hand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Use your current approach (probably the fastest IMHO)
- Manually update the tables to include the system fields (could script the database part) but you also need to update the definition of the custom table in the cms_class table too to have those new fields (which can almost be copied from another custom table definition).
- Create a new custom table using an existing custom table and add those fields.  Downside from this is you cannot use a custom table already defined in the cms_class table.
- Create some C# method to essentially create new custom tables with the current columns as well as the system columns.  Would be a "run-once" block of code.

Depending on how much time you want to spend, I think the last option is viable really.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check on this. I ended up writing one-time-use code to create the tables and migrate the data for me. Honestly it didn't end up taking too long, although the hardest part was figuring out exactly how to perform those operations with the Kentico Data API.